# How to call a function within a class with self

Tags: python

Suppose I have the following:

```
class myClass:
  def foo(self):
    # do something
```

How can I call `myClass` from inside the class without declaring an new `myClass` Object? i.e. I'd like something like

```
class myClass:
  def foo(self):
    # do something

  if __name__ == '__main__':
    # call foo
```

or without `main`:

```
class myClass:
  def foo(self):
    # do something

  # call foo
```

Right now I keep getting either the error that `self` is not defined, or the error that `foo` expects `1` argument but `0` was provided.

Comment: You can't, because that doesn't make any sense. If you want `foo` to be callable without a `myClass` instance, why is it an instance method?

Comment: you can use `foo` as a `classmethod` to achieve this.

Comment: @Soumendra If the OP really wants to call the function from *inside* the class statement, there's no class yet either. (Strictly speaking, `foo` can be called immediately as a *regular* function, although providing the correct arguments may be problematic.)

Comment: @chepner, yeah, correct. I missed the indentation and thought OP try to call from outside of the class. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot.  The function is part of the class, so to access it you must access the class first.

```
class myClass:
    def foo(self):
        # do something

myClass().foo()
```

If you just don't want to type `myClass().foo()` but only `foo` then you could just return the `myClass()` in a new function called `foo()`:

```
def foo():
    return  myClass().foo()
```

You can use `self` in a class when calling *from inside the class itself*:

```
class myClass:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def foo(self):
        pass
    def method2(self):
        self.foo()
```

This does not create a new instance of `myClass` like calling `myClass().foo()` would, and you do not need to pass the same arguments that you may have passed in `myClass`.

Answer (score 0):

Since `foo()` has a `self` parameter, that means it is an *instance method*, and therefore it is only callable from an *instance* of `myClass`.

If you want `foo` to be callable without an instance, use the `@staticmethod` decorator, and remove `self` from the parameter list.

Comment: Technically, it's an instance method because it's a function defined in the body of a `class` statement and it isn't decorated by either `@classmethod` or `@staticmethod`; the `self` parameter just means the function is prepared to receive the argument it will be passed when called.

Comment: @chepner You're right of course, `self` is not a magical name.  But in an effort to preserve my sanity, I'm deliberately ignoring any use of `self` outside of its widely accepted meaning.